# Views Dependent Filter showing when no controller value selected

Tags: 7, views

I'm using [Views Dependent Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters) to have a filter show based on the value of a filter above it. It is working for the most part but it is showing the field by default (when no controller value is selected.)

When my multiple select filter  being used as the controller, the dependent field shows even when no value is selected. For example:

Vehicle:

- Car (Set as controller)
- Boat
- Plane

Tire Size (Dependent Filter)

- Small
- Med
- Large

Tire size shows when "car" is selected but also shows when no value is selected. I believe this the module is not intended to function this way.

Is there a solution to this or a possible alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug relating the default views multiple select filter. I used the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) checkboxes and now the dependent filter works as intended.